# $element injected in controller doesn't give me updated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my script below I am trying to get the id of **li** element on ng-change event, I am injecting $element into my controller , now I can add new id to li but

> the problem is,  when I try to get the id of the li , it is **not** giving me the
>   updated values. It always returns 0.

***Here is scripts:***

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("baseCtrl", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.drivers = [];

  }
]);

app.controller("childCtrl", ['$scope', '$element',
  function($scope, $element) {

    $scope.driver = {
      name: "",
      country: ""
    };

    $scope.change = function() {

      if ($scope.driver.name && $scope.driver.country) {
        var $id = $element.data('id');

        console.log($id);

        if ($scope.$parent.drivers.length > 0 && $id > 0) {
          var $action = "update";
        } else {
          var $action = "insert";
        }


        if ($action == "update") {
          $.each($scope.$parent.drivers, function(i, v) {
            $scope.driver.id = $id;
            if ($id == v.id) { // update
              v[i] = $scope.driver;
            }
          });
        } else if ($action == 'insert') { // insert data
          //console.log($element);
          $scope.driver.id = ++$scope.$parent.id;
          $scope.$parent.drivers.push($scope.driver);
          $element.attr('data-id', $scope.$parent.id);
        }
        //console.log($scope.$parent.id);
        //console.log($scope.$parent.drivers);



      }
    };





  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="content" ng-controller="baseCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-controller="childCtrl" data-id="0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="driver.name" name="fname" ng-change="change()">
        <select name="" id="" name="country_f" ng-model="driver.country" ng-change="change($event)">
          <option value="india">India</option>
          <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="china">China</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li ng-controller="childCtrl" data-id="0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="driver.name" name="fname" ng-change="change()">
        <select name="" id="" name="country_f" ng-model="driver.country" ng-change="change()">
          <option value="india">India</option>
          <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="china">China</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li ng-controller="childCtrl" data-id="0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="driver.name" name="fname" ng-change="change()">
        <select name="" id="" name="country_f" ng-model="driver.country" ng-change="change()">
          <option value="india">India</option>
          <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="china">China</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li ng-controller="childCtrl" data-id="0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="driver.name" name="fname" ng-change="change()">
        <select name="" id="" name="country_f" ng-model="driver.country" ng-change="change()">
          <option value="india">India</option>
          <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="china">China</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any Help will really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is exactly your issue ?? i tried to create a plunker based on your code http://plnkr.co/edit/g3V1XeQEF4HaRN9paiQe?p=preview . the data-id attribute seems to be updating.

Comment: Yes data-id is updating, but when i try to pic the updated id, using $element, it gives the old id not updated value.

Comment: check the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/g3V1XeQEF4HaRN9paiQe?p=preview. I am trying to alert the updated attribute and its giving correct value.

Comment: actually , the idea is , if there is any id other than 0 is present then i want to update the parent scope object. so, i have to get the id, when some one change the value, so, i am trying to get the id very first  using this code **var $id = $element.data('id');** but it's giving me the old value. not updated one.

Comment: why not using $id = $element.attr("data-id") ? it gives you the id correctly.

Comment: No, at that place, this code too not giving me the updated value.